# Issue while compiling webpack and running local host

Tags: webpack, localhost

I am trying to run html file using web pack server, during compilation of webpack I am getting the following error in cmd but webpack is compiled successfully.

```
content is served from ./dist+/public
404s will fallback to /index.html
```

and
when I am trying to run localhost I am getting error as below

```
Cannot GET /details
```

I have tried configuring webpack.config.js file. It did not work.
Webp pack version is:

```
 "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
```

and webpack.config.js file is:

```
devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist+/public',
        port: 3000,
        devtool: 'eval',
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
```

Please help me solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong, you are passing the whole operation as a string

`contentBase: './dist+/public',`

see if this works

```
contentBase:path.join('./dist','public);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried using this, but did not work for me.